# MIKTex 2.9.6161 ssl error when trying to update

Tags: miktex

I just installed MIKTex 6161 usng the basic-miktex-2.9.6161-x64.exe package.
When I got to the start menu and select update or update admin, I get an ssl connection error:

Output from the log file is:

2017-01-10 10:07:45,781-0700 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2017-01-10 10:08:11,594-0700 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-01-10 10:08:11,595-0700 INFO  FileCopyPage - Error: SSL connect error
2017-01-10 10:36:59,681-0700 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2017-01-10 10:37:51,888-0700 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2017-01-10 10:38:05,371-0700 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-01-10 10:38:05,372-0700 INFO  FileCopyPage - Error: SSL connect error

Comment: There is a long bug report regarding this error: https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2548/ and it looks as if a work-around is to set an environment variable `set MIKTEX_MPM_REMOTESERVICE6100=multiplexor` and then to run the update manager (`mpm --admin` ).

Answer (score 3):

There is a long bug report regarding this error: https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2548/.

A work-around is to set an environment variable

older miktex:

```
MIKTEX_MPM_REMOTESERVICE6100=multiplexor
```

or newer miktex:

```
MIKTEX_MPM_REMOTESERVICE6210=multiplexor
```

(in doubt set both ...)

and then to run the update manager (admin) again to get correct binaries.

After the update it should be possible to remove the environment variables (exception: windows XP which needs it always.)

Comment: I set both variables on Windows XP, MikTex 2.9.6300 - still have an error. `https://api2.miktex.org/` doesn't work on IE. Any help?

Comment: Would you have an idea @UlrikeFischer for this very close problem https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/713069/miktex-ssl-connect-error-on-a-windows-7-miktex-2-9-7364-computer ?

Answer (score 0):

change the link from where you installing the packages. As an example change it to:
https://ftp.jaist.ac.jp

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I had to set an https_proxy in my Windows cmd console in order to run the updates.
In my company's network a https_proxy is required to connect to specific sources in the internet.
I opened a cmd console and used the following commands:

`set https_procy=...`  --> replace '...' by a valid proxy server

`set MIKTEX_MPM_REMOTESERVICE6100=multiplexor` --> stems from Ulrike Fischer's answer

`set MIKTEX_MPM_REMOTESERVICE6210=multiplexor` --> stems from at Ulrike Fischer's answer

`mpm --admin` --> stems from Ulrike Fischer's answer