# MikTex "SSL connect error" on a Windows 7 + MikTex 2.9.7364 computer

Tags: miktex, windows, miktex2.9, miktex-update

I temporarily need to add some packages to an old computer with Win7 + MikTex 2.9.7364.

I have already tried all the steps from [MIKTex 2.9.6161 ssl error when trying to update](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348011/miktex-2-9-6161-ssl-error-when-trying-to-update), and added both

```
MIKTEX_MPM_REMOTESERVICE6100=multiplexor  
MIKTEX_MPM_REMOTESERVICE6210=multiplexor
```

to the user and system environment variables. I rebooted,  but still I see in "MikTex console > Settings > Package installation > Change > Remote package repository (Internet) > Next`:

```
 SSL connect error
 code="35", url="https://api2.miktex.org/hello"
```

**How to temporarily disable HTTPS in MikTex 2.9.7364 to avoid this SSL error?**

Linked but didn't solve: https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2548/

Comment: miktex no longer support windows 7, see https://miktex.org/kb/prerequisites-2-9. Add packages manually (but be aware that new packages perhaps require newer binaries, e.g. if they rely on primitives like `\expanded` being available).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Unfortunately, I don't find 2.9.6161 anymore on internet! Here it's no longer there: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/tags and also there, there is no Windows binaries. Similar problem on CTAN. Would you know where I can find a Miktex 2.9.6161 installer? (which was supposed to work on Win7)

Comment: On CTAN, we can't find older versions: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/setup/windows-x64

Comment: it wouldn't help you. You wouldn't get the infra structure. It can't connect to the package repositories.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Why? Here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348011/miktex-2-9-6161-ssl-error-when-trying-to-update they say that 2.9.6161 + `set MIKTEX_MPM_REMOTESERVICE6100=multiplexor`  + idem `...6210=...`  would make it work. Wouldn't it? It would be great to find an old installer of 2.9.6161 to test. Would you have an archive? I found it nowhere on internet...

Comment: that answer is from 2017. We are now seven years later.  You just demonstrated that the answer no longer works. You have an old miktex installation which doesn't work. Why do you think you can repair the problem by getting another old one?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Where can I download a MikTex ISO/DVD from the Windows 7 era, containing all the packages from this date, so that I can make it work on this (legacy) computer?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't remember, was it distributed as ISO or DVD a few years ago, with a snapshot of CTAN miktex packages?  I really need Miktex to work on this old Win7 computer...